# Long bolts and short bolts

Tags: probability

> Two boxes contain long bolts and short bolts. Suppose that the box 1
>   contains 60 long bolts and 40 short bolts, and the box 2 contains 10
>   long bolts and 20 short bolts.
>
> a) We randomly select the box and randomly pick one bolt from the
>   selected box. What is the probability that the bolt is long?
>
> b) We have picked a bolt and noticed that it is long. What is the
>   probability that the bolt was picked from box 1?

I have solved it using the tree diagram the following way:

a) $$P({\text{Long}}) = P({\text{Long}}\,{\text{|}}\,{\text{Box1)  + }}\,P({\text{Long}}\,{\text{|}}\,{\text{Box2)  = }}\frac{{100}}{{130}} \cdot \frac{{60}}{{100}} + \frac{{30}}{{130}} \cdot \frac{{10}}{{30}} = \frac{7}{{13}} \approx 0.54$$

b) $$P({\text{From box1 | Long}}) = \frac{{P({\text{From box1 and Long}})}}{{P({\text{Long)}}}}{\text{ = }}\frac{{\frac{{100}}{{130}} \cdot \frac{{60}}{{100}}}}{{\frac{{100}}{{130}} \cdot \frac{{60}}{{100}} + \frac{{30}}{{130}} \cdot \frac{{10}}{{30}}}} = \frac{6}{7} \approx 0.86$$

The **teacher** marked it as wrong and provided the following answer:

a) Apply the law of total probability: $$P(A) = P({B_1})P(A|{B_1}) + P({B_2})(A|{B_2})$$ where $$\begin{gathered}
  A = {\text{The bolt is long}} \hfill \\
  {B_1} = {\text{We picked the box 1}} \hfill \\
  {B_2} = {\text{We picked the box 2}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

We know the following probabilities:

$$\begin{gathered}
  P(A|{B_1}) = \frac{3}{5} \hfill \\
  P(A|{B_2}) = \frac{1}{3} \hfill \\
  P({B_1}) = P({B_2}) = \frac{1}{2} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Now $$P(A) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3} = \frac{7}{{15}}$$

b) $$P({B_1}|A) = \frac{{P(A|{B_1})P({B_1})}}{{P(A)}} = \frac{{\frac{3}{5}\frac{1}{2}}}{{\frac{7}{{15}}}} = \frac{9}{{14}} \approx 0.214$$

P.S. Is the teacher correct?

Comment: Your calculation in a)  is not right. It should be $\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{60}{100}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{10}{30}$.  The conditional probability computed by the teacher is right.  Note that first a *box* is selected "at random," with presumably each box equally likely.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ok thanx. I think i realized that in this problem we don't consider the number of bolts that each box has as it does not affect the picking probability which is apparently 1/2.

Comment: (b) Teacher is also right here. Do you understand all the steps? If not, leave a comment saying which ones.